# Textures do not appear

Tags: java, textures, minecraft

I am trying to add a texture to an item, yet the texture just doesn't appear. I have the texture made, and in the right file directory, but while in game it doesn't display. Thus, I think it's an error in my code.

For the whole class file, see below:

```
package Moonstone;

import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLPostInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.init.Items;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraftforge.common.util.EnumHelper;

@Mod(modid = "ms", name = "Moonstone", version = "1.0")
public class MoonstoneMain {
    public static Item moonstone;

    @EventHandler
    public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {
        //All init
        moonstone = new Moonstone().setUnlocalizedName("Moonstone").setTextureName("moonstone").setMaxStac    kSize(64);
        GameRegistry.registerItem(moonstone,     moonstone.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
        //Proxy, TileEntity, entity, GUI and packet registering
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event) {    
    }

    public static CreativeTabs tabMoonstone = new CreativeTabs("tabMoonstone"){
        @Override
        public Item getTabIconItem(){
            return new ItemStack(Items.stick).getItem(); 
        }
    };
}
```

For just the item, look below-

```
moonstone = new Moonstone().setUnlocalizedName("Moonstone").setTextureName("moonstone").setMaxStackSize(64);// I have tried with ms:moonstone and without, both don't work.
GameRegistry.registerItem(moonstone, moonstone.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommended changes but not necessary:

```
First:
When registering the item you should remove the .substring(5),
having this in will name the item "Moons" instead of "Moonstone".

Second:
unlocalized names should always be lowercase and should be formatted
as modid_itemname

Third:
Package names should be lowercase, package moonstone

Fourth:
Your should make a Refstrings.java file and put the modid, version and name in it
package Moonstone

public RefStrings{
   public static String NAME = "Moonstone";
   public static String MODID = "ms";
   public static String VERSION = "1.0";
}
```

Necessary changes:

```
Your setTextureName should be passed "ms:moonstone"

You didn't post your folder structure but it should look like this:
src/main/java/Moonstone/MoonstoneMain.java
src/main/resources/assests/ms/textures/items/moonstone.png
```

it is possible that some of the recommend changes will be what fixes the problem, minecraft can be a bit finicky with naming.